# PHP cURL getting two response headers with diferent "Set-Cookie"

Tags: php, php-curl

I am having an issue making cURL call to below $url.
Looks like I am getting in response two headers with two different variables "__cfduid" and "__RequestVerificationToken".
What is the point of two different headers? Which one I should use in next step which is POST login?

```
  $url = "https://app.gpstab.com";
  $headers = [
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Host: app.gpstab.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'
  ];

  $curl = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

  curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  $response_header_array1 = get_headers($url, 1);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($response_header_array1);
  echo "</pre>";
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone...
It was my mistake and misunderstanding of `get_headers()` function. But it does  not display header from `curl_exec($curl)` execution. It simply calls again URL and gets headers.
In the next step header returned by `curl_exec($curl)` should be used.